# Getting Started with PhoneGap and JQM.. Pretty Confused

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I have just started learning PhoneGap and I want it to integrate with Jquery Mobile. I am looking for a getting started guide or something like that will help me in building a basic app before I switch to some serious development.

Can you suggest me some tutorials, books or videos for the same ?

Comment: Google much?    http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's our [tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt0) for the AppLaud Eclipse plugin which provides a bundled PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile to make it easy to create Android apps.

Also see these two videos:

- [PhoneGap API Demo with jQuery Mobile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTVsUZTvtQc&feature=plcp)
- [Intro: AppLaud Eclipse Plugin for PhoneGap / Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT02ytSSMII&feature=plcp)